# VBA Declare Function containing VARIANT types to 64 bit DLLs

Tags: c++, vba, dll, 64-bit

I have a function in C++

```
extern "C"
{
    VARIANT __stdcall foo(const VARIANT FAR& p1, const VARIANT FAR& p2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It compiles to `bar.dll` using a `.def` file that specifies the entry points and ordinals. (Yes, quite old fashioned and I'm aware `FAR` is now obsolete).

Its primary usage is in Excel, and I'm wanting to port the dll to x64 so I can use 64 bit Excel. Within VBA, I define

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function foo Lib "bar.dll" (Optional ByRef p1 As Variant, Optional ByRef p2 As Variant) As Variant
```

This (without the PtrSafe) works in 32 bit and is what I currently have. But in x64, `p1` and `p2` do not hold readable memory when I get to the C++ function.

Either I'm missing something or this is no longer supported. Can anyone help?

Comment: Nothing jumps out.  See if you have better luck if you pass the return value as a byref argument instead.